# No check box for new captcha

Tags: bug

Every so often I have to prove I'm a real human boy, despite having pretty much nothing in common with Pinocchio. I get a pop up asking me to :

> Check the CAPTCHA box, and we'll be out of your way

Well, in Firefox Developer edition, there is no captch box to check, or does it mean the link or the picture to the side?!?

So, I click the close icon at the top right to return to the post I was working on, and simply re-click the `post your answer` button and it goes straight through!

Not sure if this matters or not, but thought I'd flag it.

As an aside, does the binary actually translate to a message?

[image]

Comment: Note that you're using an unsupported browser.

Comment: I didn't know it was unsupported. Is there an official list what is/isn't supported @slhck?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: I was asked one hour ago for the first time to "check the CAPTCHA box", though no captcha box appeared. Been using stackexchange for years without problem on Ubuntu AMD64. Currently using Firefox 36.0.1 . I tried clicking on "login". I was logged in but the problem remained.